# Sixth degree polynomial problem

Tags: calculus, polynomials

If the graph of $$y = x^6 - 10x^5 + 29x^4 - 4x^3 + ax^2$$  always lies above the line $y = bx + c$, except for $3$ points where the curve intersects the line.

What is the largest value of $x$ for which the line intersects the curve?

- A) 4
- B) 5
- C) 6
- D) 7

Through general idea of graphs and with the help of a graphing calculator I have concluded the approximate look of such a curve and a line.

However, I would like to know a proper mathematical solution to this problem.

Comment: The problem is that a,b and c have specific values for such condition to be true. What can be noted is that in the 3 points of intersection the line acts as a tangent to the curve.

Comment: Are those three distinct? I drew the graph on grapher app and the 3 extremum points don't seem to be collinear.

Comment: I have written some thoughts on this question which do not constitute an answer, so I'll post it as a community wiki answer in the hopes it may be slightly useful.

Comment: As I understand the problem, $(x^6 - 10x^5 + 29x^4 - 4x^3 + ax^2)-(bx+c)$ must have have 3 double roots. Is it that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions are equivalent to:
$$
x^6-10 x^5+29 x^4-4 x^3+ax^2-bx-c=(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)^2(x-\gamma)^2
$$
Since $x^6-10 x^5+29 x^4-4 x^3+ax^2\geq bx+c$, and we know that equality holds for $3$ different $x$ values. So checking the coefficients, we have the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
 -\alpha ^2 \beta ^2 \gamma ^2-c=0 \\
 2 \alpha  \gamma ^2 \beta ^2+2 \alpha ^2 \gamma  \beta ^2+2 \alpha ^2 \gamma ^2 \beta -b=0 \\
 -\beta ^2 \alpha ^2-\gamma ^2 \alpha ^2-4 \beta  \gamma  \alpha ^2-4 \beta  \gamma ^2 \alpha -4 \beta ^2 \gamma  \alpha -\beta ^2
   \gamma ^2+a=0 \\
 2 \beta  \alpha ^2+2 \gamma  \alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2 \alpha +2 \gamma ^2 \alpha +8 \beta  \gamma  \alpha +2 \beta  \gamma ^2+2 \beta ^2
   \gamma -4=0 \\
 -\alpha ^2-4 \beta  \alpha -4 \gamma  \alpha -\beta ^2-\gamma ^2-4 \beta  \gamma +29=0 \\
 2 \alpha +2 \beta +2 \gamma -10=0 \\
\end{array}
$$
So:
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=5$$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
 -\alpha ^2-4 \beta  \alpha -4 \gamma  \alpha -\beta ^2-\gamma ^2-4 \beta  \gamma +29=\\
=-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)+29=\\
=-2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma-2)=0
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
  2 \beta  \alpha ^2+2 \gamma  \alpha ^2+2 \beta ^2 \alpha +2 \gamma ^2 \alpha +8 \beta  \gamma  \alpha +2 \beta  \gamma ^2+2 \beta ^2
   \gamma -4=\\
=-4+2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)+2\alpha\beta\gamma=0
\end{array}
$$
Thus we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha+\beta+\gamma=5\\
\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=2\\
\alpha\beta\gamma=-8
\end{array}
$$
So we have to solve:
$$
x^3-5x^2+2x+8=(x-4)(x-2)(x+1)=0
$$
So $x=4$.

**Update**

Had some time to write up a more general calculation:
$$
\left(x-\alpha\right)^{2}\left(x-\beta\right)^{2}\left(x-\gamma\right)^{2}=x^{6}+a_{5}x^{5}+a_{4}x^{4}+a_{3}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}
$$

Comparing the coefficients yields:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\left(\alpha\beta\gamma\right)^{2}-a_{0} & = & 0\\
-2\alpha\beta\gamma\left(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\alpha\gamma\right)-a_{1} & = & 0\\
(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\alpha\gamma)^{2}+2\alpha\beta\gamma(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-a_{2} & = & 0\\
-2\alpha\beta\gamma-2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\alpha\gamma)-a_{3} & = & 0\\
(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^{2}+2(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\alpha\gamma)-a_{4} & = & 0\\
-2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-a_{5} & = & 0
\end{array}
$$

Which can be further simplified to:

$$
{\displaystyle \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha\beta\gamma & = & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{16}\left(-a_{5}^{3}+4a_{4}a_{5}-8a_{3}\right)}\\
(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\alpha\gamma) & = & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{8}\left(4a_{4}-a_{5}^{2}\right)}\\
(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) & = & {\displaystyle -\frac{a_{5}}{2}}
\end{array}}
$$

Thus for the $3$ coefficients:

$$
{\displaystyle \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{0} & = & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{256}\left(-a_{5}^{3}+4a_{4}a_{5}-8a_{3}\right)^{2}}\\
a_{1} & = & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{64}\left(a_{5}^{2}-4a_{4}\right)\left(-a_{5}^{3}+4a_{4}a_{5}-8a_{3}\right)}\\
a_{2} & = & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{64}\left(5a_{5}^{4}-24a_{4}a_{5}^{2}+32a_{3}a_{5}+16a_{4}^{2}\right)}
\end{array}}
$$

Therefore:

$$
\left(x-\alpha\right)\left(x-\beta\right)\left(x-\gamma\right)=x^{3}+\frac{a_{5}x^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{8}\left(4a_{4}-a_{5}^{2}\right)x+\frac{1}{16}\left(a_{5}^{3}-4a_{4}a_{5}+8a_{3}\right)
$$

Which has three disctinct reals roots, iff:

$$
\frac{1}{128}\left(-25a_{5}^{6}+180a_{4}a_{5}^{4}-320a_{3}a_{5}^{3}-304a_{4}^{2}a_{5}^{2}+1152a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}-64a_{4}^{3}-864a_{3}^{2}\right)>0
$$

Comment: In your first line, how do you know that the roots must necessarily be repeated? For example couldn't it be $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)^{2}(g(x)) = 0 $ where g(x) is a quadratic with imaginary roots?

Comment: Then for a small enough $\varepsilon$, for $\alpha+\varepsilon$ and $\alpha-\varepsilon$ the sign of $(x-\alpha)$ is different, while all the other signs remain the same, so we cannot have the inequality for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Okay you've convinced me, +1

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user424809 remember to accept his answer if you thought it was good

Answer (score 2):

I begin the computation by the same expression as @Ákos Somogyi

$$\tag{1}x^6-10 x^5+29 x^4-4 x^3+ax^2-bx-c=\underbrace{(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)^2(x-\gamma)^2}_{p(x)^2}$$

But I consider at once that this polynomial is equal to

$$\tag{2}p(x)^2=(x^3+ux^2+vx+w)^2$$

for certain coefficients $u,v,w.$ Expanding the square in (2):

$$\tag{3}x^6+2ux^5+(u^2+2v)x^4+(2uv+w)x^3+(2uw+v^2)x^2+2vwx+w^2,$$

we easily obtain by identification of coefficients in (1) and (3):

$$u=-5, v=2, w=8.$$

from which we deduce: $a=-76, b=-32, c=-64$ and

$$p(x)=x^3-5x^2+2x+8=(x+1)(x-2)(x-4)$$

Thus the rightmost root is: $x=4$, as can be seen on the picture below. This picture represents the curve with equation $y=x^6-10x^5+29x^4-4x^3-76x^2$ and the straight line with equation $y=-32x-64$, tangent to the curve at 3 differents points.

[image]

Comment: I have added a graphical representation.

Answer (score 1):

As there are three double roots, $$x^6 - 10x^5 + 29x^4 - 4x^3 + ax^2-bx-c$$ is a perfect square, and we can evaluate its square root.

Looking at the first two terms,

$$x^6-10x^5\leftrightarrow(x^3-5x)^2=x^6-10x^5\cdots$$

Next

$$x^6-10x^5+29x^4\leftrightarrow(x^3-5x^2+px)^2=x^6-10x^5+(2p+25)x^4\cdots$$ so that $p=2$.

Then

$$x^6-10x^5+29x^4-4x^3\leftrightarrow(x^3-5x^2+2x+q)^2=x^6-10x^5+29x^4+(2q-20)x^3\cdots$$ and $q=8$.

The roots of

$$x^3-5x^2+2x+8$$ are $-1, 2$ and $\color{green}4$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the lines $y = x^{2}(x^{4}-10x^{3}+29x^{2}-4x+a)$ and $y = bx + c$

With $x^{2}(x^{4}-10x^{3}+29x^{2}-4x+a) \geq bx + c$

Let's call the $3$ points of intersection $x_{1}, x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$, with $x_{1}<x_{2}<x_{3}$

Let $h(x) = x^{6}-10x^{5}+29x^{4}-4x^{3}+ax^{2}$

Then at the $3$ points of intersections, $h'(x_{i}) = b$

We want the equation

$x^{2}(x^{4}-10x^{3}+29x^{2}-4x+a) =  bx + c$

to have $x_{1},x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$ as its $3$ distinct solutions.

$x^{6}-10x^{5}+29x^{4}-4x^{3}+ax^{2}- bx - c =0$

$(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3})f(x) = 0$ where $f$ is some function of $x$.

It is clear that $f$ would be a cubic, which would have at least $1$ solution to $f(x) = 0$. So then we require that either, one of our points of intersection is a root of $f(x)$ and the quadratic remaining has no real roots, or $f(x)$ has up to $3$ roots equal to our points of intersection.

Now consider the cases:

$x_{3} = 4: 1024 +16a = 4b + c $

$x_{3} = 5: 2000 + 25a = 5b + c$

$x_{3} = 7: 17836 + 49a = 7b + c$

These are all the 'conditions' I can think of. The inequality seems rather complex and hard to make use of.